# ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException in QuickSort Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging, quicksort

I'm trying out an implementation of QuickSort but getting an

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at com.JavaReference.QuickSort.swap(QuickSort.java:50)
at com.JavaReference.QuickSort.randPartition(QuickSort.java:20)
at com.JavaReference.QuickSort.randSort(QuickSort.java:12)
at com.JavaReference.QuickSort.randSort(QuickSort.java:13)
at com.JavaReference.QuickSort.randSort(QuickSort.java:13)
at com.JavaReference.QuickSort.randSort(QuickSort.java:13)
at com.JavaReference.QuickSort.randSort(QuickSort.java:13)
at com.JavaReference.QuickSort.randSort(QuickSort.java:8)
at com.JavaReference.QuickSort.main(QuickSort.java:59)
```

Here's my source code[[here.]](http://pastebin.com/aAaki50K)

Im a newbie to programming so any advice on where Im going wrong  would be appreciated.

EDIT:Added entire stacktrace

Comment: Post the full stack trace please.

Comment: @PéterTörök:Added entire stack trace.

Comment: I would write on paper the input data, and try to sort it by hand, following the code you wrote. It should help to identify where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>My suspect is line 30:</strike>

```
            int i =left-1;
```

Since `left` is initially 0, `i` will become -1. Then on line 35 you call

```
                            swap(a,i,j);
```

and bang.

OK, from the stack trace it seems my first guess was wrong.

Second guess: from the stack trace it shows that the array is partitioned 4 times, and then at the 5th attempt the exception comes. It is thrown on line 50:

```
int temp= array[a];
```

`a` is the first parameter to `swap`. The call to `swap` on line 20 was

```
swap(a,right,randPivot);
```

thus `right` is -1 at that point. This value comes from here (line 13):

```
randSort(a,left,pivot-1);
```

If `pivot` is 0 at this point, shit happens. And it can become 0 since it is taken as a random value between `left` and `right`, inclusive. (And actually, that is a mistake, as for effective partitioning, `pivot` should fall *between* `left` and `right`, noninclusive.) Currently, the probability of `pivot` becoming 0 increases as the leftmost partition becomes smaller. You need to introduce a check for this (or, more generally, to detect array partitions of size 1, which can't be partitioned further), to stop the recursion in time.

Comment: Your answer made me look at the code in the right perspective, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 does always tell you you're trying to call an array at an index which doesn't exist in this array.
Here the value of a ( Try to do System.out.println(a) which will show you the value of a) becomes at one time of the excecution -1.
So you try to call array[-1] which causes the exception because the array begins at an index of 0.
you need to change your algorithm so your method swap will only be called with values  int[] array, value between 0 and array.length-1, value between 0 and array.length

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access to the element of the array with the index -1. This always throws an Exception. Check that the index (a >= 0).

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint. This function:

```
public static void randSort(int a[],int left,int right)
```

leads to infinite recursion (it will call itself forever). At some point you will call `swap` with arguments left=0 and right=-1 (because `randPartition` returns 0 at some point).

Answer (score 0):

I think it does not make sense to allow the pivot to be either **left** or **right**. This is because **pivot** should be used to separate two parts of the arry to be sorted (divide and conquer). To be most efficient, both parts should be equal in size.

So if **left** and **right** differ only by one, you should end recursion anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well folks,
It was my bad earlier, Id missed a critical

```
 \\\Other code 
 if(left<right){
    int pivot=randPartition(a,left,right);// testing purposes

    randSort(a,left,pivot-1);........
 ...
```

in the    randSort() function, I guess this was making right go negative .Sorry for all the noise.